# Postgres insert query data ordering while using row_number()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query as shown below:

```
insert
    into
    temp(item_cd,
    part_seq,
    part_nm,
    reg_dm,
    upd_dm,
    data_output_dm,
    is_active)
  select
    item_cd,
    seq,
    header,
    to_char(now() at time zone 'JST', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MMHH'),
    to_char(now() at time zone 'JST', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MMHH'),
    now(),
    true
  from
    (
    select
      item_cd,
      row_number() over (partition by item_cd) as seq,
      header 
    from
      (
  with cte as(
      select
        sdg.item_cd,
        sdg.shop_no,
        min(sdg.disp_no::numeric)as disp_no
      from
        shop_disp_goods sdg
      join item i 
    on
        sdg.item_cd = i.item_cd
        and i.size_set_flg is false
      group by
        sdg.item_cd,
        sdg.shop_no
  )
      select
        sdg.item_cd,
        sdg.shop_no ,
        sdg.disp_no ,
        unnest(string_to_array(cd.cd_dtl_exp, '|'))as header
      from
        cte
      join
      sdg
  on
        cte.item_cd = sdg.item_cd
        and cte.shop_no = sdg.shop_no
        and cte.disp_no = sdg.disp_no::numeric
      join sd
  on
        sd.shop_no = cte.shop_no
        and sd.disp_no = sdg.disp_no
      join 
     cd
  on
        sd.part_cd = cd.cd_dtl_no
    ) s
    ) s
    order by item_cd, seq
```

While I do the select query the item_cd, header and seq order is shown in the gui client as I expected. When the data gets inserted into the temp table that order is not preserved. What I want is that the sequence should be generated in the same order as the order of unnested value of cd_dtl_exp column when inserted into the temp table

Comment: Unrelated, but: the final `order by` is useless as there is no implied sort order of rows in a table which needs to be preserved

Comment: If you move the `unnest()` into the from clause (where it belongs) then you can use `unnest(...) with ordinality` which will return an number that indicates the index of the element in the array which removes the need of the `row_number()` completely

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ORDER BY header` in the `OVER` clause in your window function:

```
row_number() over (partition by item_cd order by header) as seq,
```

This will ensure that the generated `row_number` will have the order you desire.